# How to create a table in SQL Server using RevoScaleR?

Tags: r, sql-server

I'd like to able manage table on SQL Server via my R script and RevoScaleR library. 
I have Machine Learning Services installed on a local instance and Microsoft R Client as an interpreter for R. I can get a connection to the server.
However, it seems, I can't create a table on the server.

I've tried:

```
> predictionSql = RxSqlServerData(table = "PredictionLinReg", connectionString = connStr)
> predict_linReg = rxPredict(LinReg_model, input_data, outData = predictionSql, writeModelVars=TRUE)
```

...which returns:

> Error in rxCompleteClusterJob(hpcServerJob, consoleOutput,
>   autoCleanup) :    No results available - final job state: failed

Help would be appreciated. New to R.

Comment: I dont know R but can you send sql statements to the database, like for example `create table myTable(ID int null);` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've forgotten to insert the second line of mine script. Just edited.